# Type.Forname() throws null pointer exception

Tags: apex, type

I have a managed package 'A' which has a global interface with a method

```
global interface Ivehichle {

string getEngineName() ;
```

}

In the managed package B, i am implementing this interface Ivehicle in a public class

```
public with sharing class car implements PackageANameSpace.IVehicle {
public String getEngineName() {
   return '';
}
```

}

Now in my managed package A when i try to retrieve the type and instance of the managed package B class

```
Type t = Type.forName('NameSpaceofPackageB','car');
IVehicle vehicle = (Ivehicle)t.newinstance();
```

the type.forname throws a null pointer exeption

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's expected, as you can't directly access public classes in that manner. You'll want a global class you can call. To avoid exposing implementation details, the method itself can be public.

You probably want to just create a Factory instead. At a very basic level...

```
global class Factory implements Callable {
  public Object call(String action, Map<String, Object> args) {
    switch on action {
      when 'getCar' { return new Car(); }
      when else { return null; }
    }
  }
}
```

You can leave car as `public` with this implementation:

```
// From package A
Callable factory = (Callable)Type.forName('PackageBNamespace','Factory').newInstance();
IVehicle car = factory.call('getCar',null);
```

Answer (score 2):

The class `car` is declared `public`. As such, it is not exposed in the context of managed package A, regardless of the fact that it implements an interface defined in that managed package.

If you want `car` to be accessible in package A, declare it as `global`.

Otherwise, you would need to build these packages as second-generation managed packages and make use of the [`@namespaceAccessible`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_NamespaceAccessible.htm) annotation. That feature does not apply to first-generation managed packages.